AhoyEmail gem token is not stored in the database
I have a rails application. I have added the ahoy_email gem to track the emails.
I have added the AhoyEmail.default_options[:message] = true
The token in the AhoyMessage table is not being stored in the database. Every time, it gets a nil value when created.
Why does this happen, token is not populated?

It looks like the default is to not save tokens Source. Try setting AhoyEmail.save_token = true. Additionally it appears that this only applies to Mailer's with track_clicks  turned on Source so make sure that is setup accodringly as well.
